# 'DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead'

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i am trying to make a bot dm all members with a specific role, but get the error: `DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead`

here is the code:

```js
  //dm
  if (command === "dm") {
    const args = message.content.split(" ");
    const roleArgs = args.slice(0, 1);
    const messageArgs = args.slice(1)
    
    const role = message.guild.roles.find("Members")
    if (!role) return message.reply('There is not such a role!');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < message.guild.members.size; i++) {
        if (message.guild.members.roles.has(role.id)) {
            message.guild.members.user.send(messageArgs.join(" "))
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: you need to pass a function into the find() method, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a function for the find. Replace this line:

```
const role = message.guild.roles.find("Members")
```

With this line:

```
const role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Members");
```

EDIT:
For your other issue, you are trying to access role of multiple members. That does not work. Replace your for loop with this:

```
message.guild.members.forEach(m => if(m.roles.has(role.id)) { m.user.send(messageArgs.join(" ")) });
```

Comment: new issue. `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined`

Comment: @Golden_ edited my answer to add the other correction.

Comment: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined` sorry. im new to this and probably missing something

Comment: [Guild.members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members) is a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) - use .get() on it instead of bracket accessors `[]`. Check the docs when you have an error!

Comment: Thanks to @Klaycon I edited my answer again. Did not test it. Hopefully it works now.

Comment: ```  //dm
  if (command === "dm") {
    const args = message.content.split(" ");
    const roleArgs = args.slice(0, 1);
    const messageArgs = args.slice(1)
    
    const role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Members");
    if (!role) return message.reply('There is not such a role!');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < message.guild.members.size; i++) {
      message.guild.members.forEach(m => if(m.roles.has(role.id)) {
      m.user.send(messageArgs.join(" ")) 
    });
    }
        }```
?

Comment: @Golden_ No, the forEach line doesn't have to be in a loop. Remove the for loop.

Comment: ```
  //dm
  if (command === "dm") {
    const args = message.content.split(" ");
    const roleArgs = args.slice(0, 1);
    const messageArgs = args.slice(1)
    
    const role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Members");
    if (!role) return message.reply('There is not such a role!');
    
    
      message.guild.members.forEach(m => if(m.roles.has(role.id)) {
      m.user.send(messageArgs.join(" ")) 
    });
    }
```
getting red on visual studio

Comment: @Golden_ at this point you should probably open up a new question because debugging in the comment section like this is a pain and it is not the same issue anymore.